# How to set TLS version in Azure Data Factory Generic REST Linked Service?

Tags: azure-data-factory, linked-service

I have a Generic REST Linked Service in Azure Data Factory which will be used as a Source. I need to set the SSL protocol to TLS1.2 because it is failing with certain endpoints with QUIC (http/3).

Any ideas on where to set that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [REST linked service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-rest?tabs=data-factory#linked-service-properties)

> In REST linked service `enableServerCertificateValidation` property is
> used to validate server-side TLS/SSL certificate when connecting to
> the endpoint. This is set to `true` by default.

Also, in ADF, you can add `EncryptionMethod=1` in the connection string (in the Linked Service). This will use SSL/TLS as the encryption method. TLS version used is 1.2